# Change Office-Addins Excel startup file

Tags: reactjs, excel, visual-studio-code, office-js

I am developing addins for Excel but every time I do a "npm start" it boots a new Excel file with a name like this:

> Excel add-in 0c735508-100c-4734-90da-d3618b52c325.xlsx

This is no disaster but instead of a blank workbook I would like to start an existing workbook which contains data to work with. Otherwise I always have to copy in data manually before I can test my next iteration of code. In Visual studio 2017 it was possible to change the startup file. But with VSCode I have no idea how to do this. I have searched for entries in the package.json, the Manifest,Tsconfig and also in the launch.json file. But I cannot find a spot where the default file can be changed.
So I would like to change my settings, in order to change the startup file. But I do not know if it is even possible?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using the way of sideload to load the addin to Excel. You can start a localhost web server by running command "npm run dev-server". After the server is started, you can start Excel and open your existing workbook. Then you can locate the addin in "My Addins" dropdown list (Insert->My Addins) and insert it from there.

Comment: Hi xiaochun. Thanks for your reply. But does this mean that I cannot set a default startup file? so if I run "npm start" that that file gets started every time in debug mode?

Comment: Then you may can put the workbook into a startup folder. Following steps shows how to config startup folder:

1. File > Options > Advanced.

2. Under General, in the "At Startup, open all files in box", type the full path of the folder that you want to use as the startup folder.

Because Excel will try to open every file in the startup folder, make sure that you specify a folder that contains only files that Excel can open.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Where are those options? In VScode? Because in VS code I do not have Options I have preferences in File->preferences?

Comment: In Excel. It is the setting of Excel.